# Compute $\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2} \sin((m-1)x)\sin(mx)\sin((m+1)x)dx$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $m$ be a natural odd number. Compute:
>   $$\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2} \sin((m-1)x)\sin(mx)\sin((m+1)x)dx.$$

I tried using the integral property:

$$\int_0^af(x)dx=\int_0^af(a-x)dx,$$

and then adding them up but it doesn't work... I'm thinking maybe I should group the factors in some way... can I get some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:
$$\sin({(m+1)x})\cdot \sin{((m-1)x)}=\\
\frac 12[\cos((m+1)x-(m-1)x)-\cos((m+1)x+(m-1)x)]=\\
\frac 12[\cos(2x)-\cos (2mx)].\\
$$
Hence:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2} \sin((m-1)x)\sin(mx)\sin((m+1)x)dx=\\
\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\frac 12[\cos(2x)-\cos (2mx)]\sin(mx)dx=\\
\color{red}{\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\sin(mx)\cos(2x)dx}-\color{blue}{\frac 12\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\sin(mx)\cos (2mx)dx}=\\
\color{red}{\frac12 \int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\frac12[\sin(mx+2x)-\sin(mx-2x)]dx}-\\
\color{blue}{\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac \pi2}\frac12[\sin(mx+2mx)-\sin(mx-2mx)]dx}=\color{red}{\frac14\left[-\frac{1}{m+2}\cos{(mx+2x)+\frac{1}{m-2}\cos(mx-2x)}\right]\bigg{|}_0^{\pi/2}}-\\
\color{blue}{\frac14\left[-\frac{1}{3m}\cos{(3mx)-\frac{1}{m}\cos(mx)}\right]\bigg{|}_0^{\pi/2}}=\\
\cdots$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Use formulas for $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ and $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ to obtain first what is $\sin x\sin y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sin(nx) = \frac{ e^{inx} - e^{-inx}}{2i}$$